# Unsupported hg version hg 1.9..3 - Expected at least hg 2.0.0

Tags: android, mercurial, andengine

I am trying to install AndEngine. I have installed Mercurial and am trying to clone from
https://code.google.com/p/andengine but I get the message "Problem occurred" - Unsupported hg version hg 1.9..3 - Expected at least hg 2.0.0. java.lang.exception

How can I upgrade to hg 2.0.0. How do I install it. When I did a "yum install hg" it only installed hg 1.9.3

Also it appears the above andengine code has moved. What is the new link for cloning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the latest source is here on github

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Comment: Thanks. Could you let me know to how to fix the mercurial issue?

Comment: can't help there as I don't use it. IIRC, Mercurial doesn't work with GitHub anyway - could be wrong about that though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the hg issue by downloading mercurial-2.4.1-1.fc18.i686.rpm from the mercurial site and then installing it. There was some problem with the earlier 2.0.0 version I suppose.